# I want to render current timing value to HTML at interval of every seconds in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to render current timing value to HTML at interval of every seconds using reactjs. i pasted code below. I got error when i run below code.

```
import react from "react";

**Defined class**
export default class IndependentTimer extends react.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: ""
        };

        this.customFunction = this.customFunction.bind(this);
    }

**This function is responsible for generating current time.**   
    customFunction() {
        console.log("customFunDis display!");
        return (<h1> Time is : {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} </h1>);
    }

**render function**
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {**What to do here?**}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

** Error I Got is : **
I got that error at every interval of time.

VM413:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
setInterval (async)     
render  @   index.js:31245
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: I think you got enough answers ! :)

Comment: `Yes. i got the answer. Thanks.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Few things that you need to keep in mind'

First: You have a typo in creating your React Component. It should extends `React.Component` and you need to import `react` with upper case as `import React from 'react'` since it internally uses `React.createElement` which will otherwise fail.

Secondly: setInterval takes the first argument as a function and not a returned HTML. When you write

```
setInterval(this.customFunction(),1000)
```

you are executing the `customFunction` every 1 second and it returns an HTML which is incorrect. Also setInterval returns an integer which is the unique id for the timer so

```
   <div>
                {
                    setInterval(this.customFunction(),1000)
                }
            </div>
```

wont work. You should have a setInterval in the componentDidMount function and then store the timer value in state using setState which re-renders your component so that your change is reflected

```js
class IndependentTimer extends React.Component {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.state = {
                    time: ""
                };

                this.customFunction = this.customFunction.bind(this);
            }

            componentDidMount() {
                console.log("timer display!");
                this.timer = setInterval(this.customFunction,1000)
            }

            componentWillUnmount() {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
            }
            //Custom function which calculates current time.

 customFunction() {
        console.log("customFunDis display!");
        this.setState({time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()});
 
 }

render() { 
            return (
                <div>
                 <h1> Time is : {this.state.time} </h1>
                </div>
            );
        }

    }
    
ReactDOM.render(<IndependentTimer/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: `Yes. i got the answer. Thanks.`

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Placing a `setInterval()` within your `render()` method will create a brand new `setInterval()` every time your component updates.

Best practice is to create one single `setInterval()` method within your component's `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
}
```

You must also clear your `setInterval()` whenever you expect your component to dismount:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.timer)
}
```

You should end up with something similar to the code below.

```
// React.
import React from 'react'

// Independent Timer.
export default class IndependentTimer extends React.Component {

  // Constructor.
  constructor(props) {

    // Super Props.
    super(props)

    // State.
    this.state = {
      time: new Date()
    }
  }

  // Render.
  render() {
    const time = this.state.time
    return `${time * 1}`
  }

  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
  }

  // Tick.
  tick = () => {
    console.log('Tick.')
    return this.setState({time: new Date()})
  }

  // Will Unmount.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
}
```

You might also want to check out [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) from the official React docs on creating a clock component.

Comment: `Yoo. i got the answer. Thanks.`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {time:new Date()};
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.sTimer = this.sTimer.bind(this);
  }

  startTimer() {
   setInterval(this.sTimer, 1000)
  }
  sTimer() {
   this.setState({
   time:new Date()
   });
  }
  render() {
   return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
      {this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString()}
    </div>
  );
}

}export default App;
```

Use this class it may help you..